# Why isn't お前 marked with a particle in "お前やるじゃん"?

Tags: translation, particles

The sentence

> お前やるじゃん。

can be translated as

> You're good at this.

or perhaps more literally (if I'm not mistaken) as

> You doing completely, aren't you?

**Question:** Why isn't お前 marked with any sort of particle? It seems to me お前 is acting as the subject of the sentence here, so shouldn't it be marked with either a が or a は particle?

Answer (score 3):

Actually both は and が don't make sense.

This やるじゃん (or やるー, やるじゃないか, やるね, やりますね, etc.) is a fixed expression to praise the ability of the person in front of the speaker. This type of short やる doesn't take an explicit subject/topic, just as "Well done", "Good job", "Way to go" and so on are said without any subject in English. Here お前 is used to address the person ("(Hey) you!"), so it doesn't take any particle.

- [【豆知識24】『やるね!/いいね!』は英語で?](https://toshian.net/mame-24/)

That said, やる is occasionally used also as part of a longer sentence like so:

> 彼はなかなかやる人だそうです。
> I've heard he is quite a capable person.

Comment: Thanks! The comparison to "Well done", "Good job", and similar English phrases makes it really clear why there's no particle.

Just to confirm: do you think a good (but quite literal) translation of this sentence is something like: *"You! You do, don't you?"* (spoken in a complimentary way)?

Comment: @George Any good translation should be idiomatic in the target language, which *"You! You do, don't you?"* is not. At best that's an approximate *transliteration*. However, the "You!" with exclamation mark doesn't make sense in this context. That would correspond to something like "(おい！)お前！やるじゃん！" as separate utterances, which would be kinda odd. Also, translating this やる as "do" is too literal, because this やる implies "do *well*", with more emphasis on the *well* part than the *do* part. (BTW, my translation would simply be an emphatic: "*Not bad!*"; I think that captures the casual context).